# Clear button at uisearchbar not working at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, uisearchbar

I created a search bar programmatically and added to my view using the codes below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPositionForSearchBar, yPositionForSearchBar, widthForSearchBar, heightForSearchBar)];
        UIView *bg = [[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        searchBar.delegate = self;
        searchBar.placeholder = @"Search record";
        for(UIView *view in searchBar.subviews){
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
                UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)view;
                tf.delegate = self;
                break;
            }
        }
        [bg removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview: searchBar];
}
```

The code is implemented with UISearchBarDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate.

I have tried using

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    NSLog(@"cancel clicked");
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"clear");
    [self performSelector:@selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked:) withObject:searchBar afterDelay: 0.1];
    return YES;
}
```

and yet, the text inside the searchBar is not cleared at all when i click on the "clear button" - a circle with a "X" inside.

The clear button works when I implemented it in IB. Wonder why?

Kindly advice, many thanks.

Comment: if you set breakpoints on either delegate method, does any breakpoint hit?

Comment: nope it didn't call the methods

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code where you actually ***add*** the search bar to your view controller (e.g. "`UISearchDisplayController`")?  You're creating the search bar programatically. How does it get added?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview: searchBar];` add the searchBar to my view

Comment: Just to add on, the text did clear only after i hold the x cross button for at least 1 ~ 2 seconds. Any idea why?

Comment: Hey Kevin, have you solved this? Your Code is working fine in my case.

Comment: Yea... im not sure why it's working suddenly too.

Answer (score 5):

This might happen if you position your search bar out of the bounds of a parent view. Then, the touches aren't delivered to your searchBar properly. This also affects text editing controls like copy & paste.

Comment: Also if the somewhere in the code, isUserInteractionEnabled = false has been set for the textField (such as in a delegate method related to editing), the clear button will become unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code it work fine on device as well as on simulator.